# Javascript composite RegExp containing sub-RegExps

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I have written a RegExp which correctly validates a single currency, eg.`EUR` or `USD`:

```
const ccyRegEx = new RegExp(currencies.join('|'), 'i');
```

Which produces something like `EUR|USD|JPY|GBP...` given `currencies = ["EUR", "USD", "JPY", "GBP"...]`

How would I go about using this RegExp and the `currencies` array as input to construct a new RegExp which validates currency pairs, eg.`EURUSD`, `USDJPY`?

The `currencies` array is large and could potentially change, so I want to create this regex dynamically, not hard code all the possible permutations of currency pairs.

Same currency pairs, eg.`EUREUR` and `USDUSD` are NOT valid.
Currency pairs in different orders are valid, eg.`EURUSD` and `USDEUR`.

Comment: The same way? `curencies = [ "EURUSD", "USDJPY" ];` ? Or is the question how you construct the array `[ "EURUSD", "EURJPY", "USDEUR", "JPYEUR", "USDJPY", "JPYUSD" ]`  with `["EUR", "USD", "JPY"]` as the input?

Comment: @Shilly sorry if it was not clear but the `currencies` array is large and could potentially change, so I want to create this regex dynamically, not hard code all the possible permutations of currency pairs

Comment: Hence i ask if you want to create `[ "EURUSD", "EURJPY", "USDEUR", "JPYEUR", "USDJPY", "JPYUSD" ] with ["EUR", "USD", "JPY"] as the input. I assume that's a yes?

Comment: @Shilly ah yes, with the `currencies` array as input, I don't have an array of currency pairs unfortunately

Comment: Where do you get the `currencies` array from?

Comment: Are EUREUR or USDUSD valid? Are EURUSD & USDEUR both possible?

Comment: @Shilly a backend service, there is not a service for retrieving currency pairs unfortunately and it may take a while for that to be built so looking for a solution in the meantime

Comment: @PJProudhon same currency pairs are not valid, currency pairs in both orders are valid

Comment: `(EUR|USD|JPY|GBP){2}`

Comment: @Alexander as mentioned, wanting a dynamically created regex using `currencies` array, not hardcoded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add `{2}` to match exactly two items of your set.

For example, `/(a|b|c){2}/` will match `ab`, `ca` but not `ad`.

You can change your dynamic regular expression like this:

```js
const currencies = ["EUR", "USD", "JPY", "GBP"];
const singleMatch = new RegExp(currencies.join('|'));

console.log('single match - EUR:', singleMatch.test('EUR'));

const doubleMatch = new RegExp('(' + currencies.join('|') + '){2}');


console.log('double match - EUR:', doubleMatch.test('EUR'));
console.log('double match - USDEUR:', doubleMatch.test('USDEUR'));
console.log('double match - GBPEUR:', doubleMatch.test('GBPEUR'));
console.log('double match - GBPGDD:', doubleMatch.test('GBPGDD'));
```

Pay attention: It matches also `EUREUR`. To avoid this, you should use a negative look-behind or a negative look-ahead.

---

### Edit

I integrate the @PJProudhon implementation of the negative look-ahead, as he stated in the comments' section:

```js
const currencies = ["EUR", "USD", "JPY", "GBP"];
const doubleMatch = new RegExp('(?:(' + currencies.join('|') + ')(?!\\1)){2}');

console.log('double match - EUREUR:', doubleMatch.test('EUREUR')); //expect false
```

Thank you @PJProudhon

Comment: Ah of course, and ah yes I should have mentioned same currency pairs aren't valid, but thanks anyway!

Comment: not sure what a negative look-behind is, are you able to edit your solution to include that?

Comment: Or a negative lookahead: as in `(?:(a|b|c)(?!\1)){2}`.

Comment: Thank you @PJProudhon, I integrate your hint in the answer

Answer (score 2):

I would say to keep it simple stupid and build an intermediate array with all possibilities, example :

```
const currenciesPair = [];
const currenciesLength = currencies.length

for (let i = 0; i < currenciesLength ; i++) {

    for (let j = 0; j < currenciesLength ; j++) {
        // avoiding pair such as EUREUR, USDUSD, etc...
        if (i !== j) {
            currenciesPair.push(currencies[i] + currencies[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

And keep your regex with this array (you can also mix currenciesPair and currencies for complete possibilities) :)

Comment: I think this is the best solution that fully works, thank you :)

Comment: At least cache currencies.length in a variable if you go for this, else it'll be the slowest solution. `const currency_count = currencies.length; for ( i < currency_count ) ...` else you'll evaluate the length every time both in the inner and the outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather inefficient algo though, so depending on the amount of currencies, other options will be better.

If it's doable for the dataset, I would prefer Cristian Traìna s solution.

```js
const currencies = [ "EUR", "USD", "JPY", "GBP" ];

const product_matrix = currencies // loop over all the currencies
 .map( currency => currencies // We want to join the currency with all other currencies
  .map( pair => currency !== pair // Only do the join if the currency and its pair aren't the same
   ? `${ currency }${ pair }`
   : null )
  .filter( Boolean ) // Remove all the null values. YOu coudl use reduce instead of map to skip this step.
 )
 .flat(); // Flatten the 2 dimensional array into a one dimensional one.
 
console.log( product_matrix );
```